# TextInputLayout of support library has some bugs android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

**What I have**

I have a signup form in which I do validation using `TextWatcher`. I used `TextInputLayout` of support library to highlight the Error

**My problem**

When I input incorrect data in my `EditText` , the `TextInputLayout` turns my `EditText` to `red` color

then, when I put the correct input in my `EditText`, then change the `focus` to other field , still the first `EditText`is in red color **not changing to normal editext background**

**What I tried**

I tried setting the background of my `EditText` programatically to my custom drawable , but it give my other look and feel (other color)

Also tried to only change the `HintColor` to red of `TextInputLayout` without using the `setError()` method , still not results

**My code**

**1st approach** : giving me some other color for background

```
public boolean validateFirstName() {
        mFirstName = edFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (mFirstName.isEmpty()) {
            tiFirstName.setError(mEmptyFields);
            edFirstName.requestFocus();        
            return false;
        } else {
            tiFirstName.setError(null);
            tiFirstName.setErrorEnabled(false);
            edFirstName.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ed_line_bg));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**2nd approach** : no changes seen :(

```
public boolean validateFirstName() {
        mFirstName = edFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (mFirstName.isEmpty()) {
            edFirstName.requestFocus();
            changeTextInputLayoutColorToRed(tiFirstName);
            return false;
        } else {
            changeTextInputLayoutColorToNormal(tiFirstName);
            edFirstName.setBackground(null);
        }
        return true;
    }



public void changeTextInputLayoutColorToRed(TextInputLayout textInputLayout){
        int redColor=getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
       // textInputLayout.getEditText().setHighlightColor(redColor);
        textInputLayout.getEditText().setHintTextColor(redColor);
        textInputLayout.setError(mErrorMessage);
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
    }

    public void changeTextInputLayoutColorToNormal(TextInputLayout textInputLayout){
        int normalColor=getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color);
        //textInputLayout.getEditText().setHighlightColor(normalColor);
        textInputLayout.getEditText().setHintTextColor(normalColor);
        textInputLayout.setError(null);
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a TextWatcher as the following to my validations:

```
private class RegisterTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
 @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        switch (editText.getId()){

            case R.id.name_input:
                validateName();
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I add it to my editText in onCreate method of activity:

```
inputName.addTextChangedListener(new RegisterTextWatcher(inputName));
```

And my validation:

```
public boolean emptyField(String editText, TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String errorMessage){

        if(editText.trim().isEmpty()){

            setLayoutError(textInputLayout, errorMessage);

            return false;

        }else{

            removeError(textInputLayout);
            return true;
        }
    }


private void setLayoutError(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String error){

    if(!textInputLayout.isErrorEnabled()){
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        textInputLayout.setError(error);
        textInputLayout.getEditText().setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
    }
}

private void removeError(TextInputLayout textInputLayout){
    if(textInputLayout.isErrorEnabled()){
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        textInputLayout.getEditText().setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost looks similar to mine code ... What is the actual difference ?

Comment: Guess it has something to do with your TextWatcher or something you do when changing focus. This works for me

Comment: let me try this bro :)